# Pegar JSON depois de enviar um POST

Tags: php, json

Estou com problemas na hora de pegar a resposta que tenho depois de enviar uma requisição via POST

```
function httpPost($url, $data) {
        $curl = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        return $response;
    }
```

Depois disso queria pegar essa resposta que tenho em JSON e "separar" os campos que tenho como retorno, por exemplo:

```
$resposta = httpPost($url, $data);

$status = $resposta->{'status'};
```

Resposta que tenho quando executo:

```
{"errors":[{"type":"internal_error","parameter_name":null,"message":"Ocorreu um erro ao cancelar a transferência."}],"url":"URL","method":"post"}
```

Queria imprimir o "message" por exemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui da seguinte forma:

```
$executar_transf = httpPost($url, $data);
$resposta_fin = json_decode($executar_transf, true);

echo $resposta_fin['errors']['0']['message'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma dica é usar a função `$.get()` do JQuery:

```js
$(function () {
    $.get('exemplo.php', {
        //parametros da solicitacao
        param: 'pamametro'
    },function (data) {
        // resposta da solicitacao
        var response = data['errors'];
        console.log(response[0].message);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Um detalhe é que se você quiser mandar mais de uma parâmetro, é só separá-los por vírgula: `{ param_1: 'param_1', param_2: 'param_2' }`